# Cannot access to secrets .net core with Docker

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, environment-variables, docker-secrets

In my .net core Api i use secrets.json:

```
{"UserServiceSecretKey": "secretKey123456"}
```

Evidently in my .csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  <UserSecretsId>6da803bf-439d-4e34-8735-195d652e8366</UserSecretsId>
  <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
</PropertyGroup>
```

And use in my Startup.cs ConfigureServicesMethod():

```
 var secretKey = Configuration["UserServiceSecretKey"];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(secretKey))
            Console.WriteLine("Error: KEY UserServiceSecretKey cannot be null...");
```

If run the application **on IISExpres it works** (get the secret key).

But **if i run the Api in docker like docker-compose**, then in runtime the **secret key is not obtained**:
[image]

In my **docker-compose.override** file i have:

```
tresfilos.users.service:
environment: 
  - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT= Development
  - ASPNETCORE_URLS= https://+:443;http://+:80
ports:
  - "7002:80"
  - "7003:443"
volumes:
    - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
    - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
```

Additional, i have defined the APPDATA environment variable:

[image]

**How can i access to secret key when i run the Api in docker ?**

Comment: where did you define the APPDATA environment variable?

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath i define APPDATA in System environment variable... (
Advanced system settings)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Docker secrets are loaded into memory as files inside `/run/secrets` directory, not as mounted directory, so you need to read it from memory

There are 3 steps,

**1. docker-compose file**

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
    secrets:
      - my_secret
      - my_other_secret
secrets:
  my_secret:
    file: ./my_secret.txt
  my_other_secret:
    external: true
```

note: you can add secrets to docker either by using a file or by defining as external resource, which means that it has already been defined in Docker, either by running the docker secret create command or by another stack deployment. If the external secret does not exist, the stack deployment fails with a secret not found error.

**2. Install a nuget package**

`Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.KeyPerFile`

**3. Add a config entry to Startup.cs**

`config.AddKeyPerFile(directoryPath: "/run/secrets", optional: true);`

Comment: Why in docker-compose file, my_other_secret -> external: true ?

Comment: I added my notes on this.

Comment: the file secret.txt can be .json? the directoryPath what or where is?

Comment: `directoryPath: "/run/secrets"` you can hardcode. As docker container loads secrets in memory in /run/secrets folder. I never tried json, but the concept is `The value of my_secret is set to the contents of the file ./my_secret.txt`, so whatever you define inside the file will be treated as values. You can parse the json once you retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

In your compose file, you are mounting the dotnet usersecrets json file into the container at a path that the application host will expect - so that bit is fine - i.e the user secrets themselves are being placed inside the container and are therefore available to be loaded into its IConfiguration:

```
volumes:
    - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
```

The reason these UserSecrets are not being loaded by your application when it runs as a container is most likely because this only happens automatically for "Development" environments. If you look closely at the environment variables you are setting on the container:

```
environment: 
  - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT= Development
```

You have an extra space? I suspect this is causing `IHostEnvironment.IsDevelopment()` to returen false, and so the host won't auto add the `UserSecrets` configuration provider to the configuration builder.

Note: Another answer talks about docker secrets. The format of these is different from the UserSecrets.json secrets. Therefore if you want to just use UserSecrets.json and have those apply to your application when running it with compose, mounting in the usersecrets.json is the correct way to go, not using docker secrets. However docker secrets can be used in addition or instead of User Secrets. UserSecrets are not recommended for production scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the exact same problem just now. Turned out I was targeting the wrong directory.

In my Dockerfile the local user's app was mounted in `/app` not `/root`. Changing the volume path in the docker-compose.override solved the problem and I was able to access the user secret.

```
volumes:  
 - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/app/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
```